# simple login form using php

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm trying to write a simple login form.
But I'm always directed to the same page whatever password I enter.
I'm new to php so excuse my simple question.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        if($_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
            header ( 'Location: home.html ');
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Password";
            exit ;  
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <form action="index.php" method ="POST">
        Please Enter the Password:
        </br>
        <input type= "password" name= "password" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Go!"  />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If your coded file is named `index.php` as is the one for your `action`, then it should work, as it did for my test. When in doubt, use `action=""` instead of `action="index.php"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
metod ="POST"
```

to:

```
method ="POST"
```

Comment: +1 , For the eagle eyes ;)

Comment: thanksss! didn't notice that! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Its not `metod`, its `method`
2. You need an enctype in the form, in general you can use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
       if($_POST['password'] == 'admin') 
       {
           header ( 'Location: home.html ');
       }
       else 
       {
           echo "Wrong Password";
           exit ;  
       }
    }
 ?>
 <html>
 <form action="index.php" method ="POST">
  Please Enter the Password:
  </br>
 <input type= "password" name= "password" />
 <input type = "submit" name="submit" value = "Go!"  />

 </form>
```

Comment: why "?>" at the end of ur code?

Comment: I suppose he just forgot to remove it.^^

Comment: @Ashish yes it was typo

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if($_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
        header ( 'Location: home.html ');
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Password";
        exit ;  
    }
}
?>
<html>
<form action="<?echo $PHP_SELF;?>"  method ="POST">
    Please Enter the Password:
    </br>
    <input type= "password" name= "password" />
    <input type = "submit" value = "Go!"  />
</form>
```

Comment: If the form action php code is in same page should write as "form action="<?echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post"> .

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this code. use # in action .

```
       if($_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
           header ( 'Location: home.html ');
       }
       else {
           echo "Wrong Password";
           exit ;
       }
   }
   ?>
   <html>
   <form action="#" method="post">
       Please Enter the Password:
       </br>
       <input type= "password" name= "password" />
       <input type = "submit" value = "Go!"  name="submit" />
   </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
            header ('Location:process.php');
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong Password";
            exit ;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="enclosedHTMLtag.php" method="post">
        Please Enter the Password:
        </br>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

I wrote this code at `enclosedHTMLtag.php` and I'm submitting this form at `enclosedHTMLtag.php` its working if you want to submit this form at any file change this `action="enclosedHTMLtag.php"` into `action="your_file_name.php"`.

More simple is if you want to submit the form at the same page use this `<form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]'?>" method="post">` what ever is the page name it will always submit at the same page, my page name is `enclosedHTMLtag.php`, `<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]'?>` function submit at the `enclosedHTMLtag.php`.